# Область видимости глобальных переменных

Tags: javascript

Почему глобальная переменная state.totalNLines при выходе из функции parseData() становится равна 0?

В консоле выдает:

json start

json end

totalNLines = 0

parseData totalNLines = 3

```
<script>
var state= {
    completeStructData:[],
    completeFlatData:[],
    totalNLines:0
}
console.log('json start');

d3.json("data2.json", function(error, data) {
    parseData(data);
 });

console.log('json end');
console.info(state.completeStructData);
console.info(state.completeFlatData);
console.log('totalNLines = ' + state.totalNLines);

function parseData(rawData) {

    var dateObjs = rawData.length ? rawData[0].data[0].data[0].timeRange[0] instanceof Date : false;

    for (var i = 0, ilen = rawData.length; i < ilen; i++) {
        var group = rawData[i].group;
        state.completeStructData.push({
            group: group,
            lines: rawData[i].data.map(function (d) {
                return d.label;
            })
        });

        for (var j = 0, jlen = rawData[i].data.length; j < jlen; j++) {
            for (var k = 0, klen = rawData[i].data[j].data.length; k < klen; k++) {
                state.completeFlatData.push({
                    group: group,
                    label: rawData[i].data[j].label,
                    timeRange: dateObjs ? rawData[i].data[j].data[k].timeRange : [new Date(rawData[i].data[j].data[k].timeRange[0]), new Date(rawData[i].data[j].data[k].timeRange[1])],
                    val: rawData[i].data[j].data[k].val,
                    labelVal: rawData[i].data[j].data[k][rawData[i].data[j].data[k].hasOwnProperty('labelVal') ? 'labelVal' : 'val']
                });
            }

            state.totalNLines++;

        }
    }
    console.log('parseData totalNLines = ' + state.totalNLines);
}
```

Переписал вызов так:

```
(async function() {
    await d3.json("data2.json", await function(error, data) {
    parseData(error,data);

});})();
```

Ничего не изменилось.
Затем переписал так:

```
function getDate(callback){
    d3.json("data2.json", function(error, data) {
    if (!error)
    callback.call(data);
});
}

getDate(function(){parseData(this)});
```

Ничего не изменилось.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а с чего вы взяли, что это так? обратите внимание на порядок строк в вашем выводе и коде, и постарайтесь на данном примере понять, когда будет выполнен синхронный код и асинхронный обработчик

Comment: Я вижу что порядок не верный, но почему в массивах данные оказываются а в переменной нет?

Comment: @Knyaz, потому что когда ты проверяешь значение переменной, оно еще не установилось. Подробнее смотри в дубликате.

Comment: Это я понял, я не понял почему массивы оказываются заполнены, ведь они заполняются там же где инкременируется переменная. Если переменная не успевает установится то и массивы должны быть пусты, а это не так.

Comment: Попробовал async await, не работает или я что то делаю не так. Подскажите как мне выйти из этой ситуации?
    (async function() {
        await d3.json("data2.json", await function(error, data) {
        parseData(error,data);
    });})();

Comment: @Knyaz, да, ты делаешь не так. массивы у тебя заполняются в коллбэке. Коллбэк вызывается тогда, когда придут данные, а состояние переменной ты проверяешь не дожидаясь этого.

Comment: Мало просто понаписать `await` где попало, надо прочитать  дубликат и посмотреть где именно его надо писать. И надо ли его писать именно в твоем случае.

Comment: Обрати внимание, что внутри коллбэка все показывается верно. Так как ты уже заполнил массивы. именно поэтому у тебя `parseData totalNLines = 3` - до вывода этой строки любой вывод вернет 0 либо undefined.

Comment: Я вызываю отображение в лог подряд, сначала 2 массива затем счетчик, в массивах данные есть а в счетчике нет (console.info(state.completeStructData);
console.info(state.completeFlatData);
console.log('totalNLines = ' + state.totalNLines);). Может дело все таки не в "бобине"?

Comment: Я не понимаю! Можете продемонстрировать как надо?

Comment: @Knyaz, добавил еще дубликат.

Comment: @Knyaz, дело в бобине, просто добавь вывод `console.info(state.completeStructData.length);` или `console.info(JSON.stringify(state.completeStructData));`

Comment: @Grundy Ты прав дело в бобине, но как переделать чтобы работало так как нужно я так и не понял.

Comment: Все дошло! Всем Спасибо!